# ¿Puedo actualizar una tabla cuando se ingrese un dato en la base de datos?

Tags: php, javascript, html

Tengo una duda sobre sí se puede actualizar una tabla que tengo con registros llamados desde la base de datos, pero pues, sí tengo la pagina abierta y hago una modificación en la base de datos, me toca actualizar toda la pagina para que se vean los cambios, he estado intentando buscar pero no he encontrado información relevante, espero puedan ayudarme, ya sea que se tenga que hacer por jquery, ajax, o cualquiera, quiero intentar implementarlo, dejaré el codigo de la tabla en `html`

`HTML`

```
<div class='container text-center shadow p-5 mb-5 bg-white rounded' style="width: 5000px">
<a class='btn btn-success btn-lg btn-block' href="/Jomar/users_control/controller/ControlAsisController.php?action=registrar">Registrar</a>
    <?php        
        if($datos == null){
            echo "<br> <h3> No se encontraron registros <h3>";
            echo "<br> <img src='\Jomar\users_control\images\clean.png' alt='vacio' width='200' />";
        }else{
    ?>
        <div class='d-flex justify-content-center' id="contentTable">
            <table class='table table-stripped' border=1 id="table">
                <thead class= 'thead-dark'>
                    <tr>
                        <th>#</th>
                        <th>Fecha</th>
                        <th>Documento</th>
                        <th>Nombres</th>
                        <th>Apellidos</th>
                        <th>Sede</th>
                        <th>Siglas</th>                                                  
                        <th>Nota</th>                        
                        <th>Acciones</th>                        
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    <a href="/Jomar/users_control/controller/ControlAsisController.php?action=todos"></a>
                    <?php
                        for($i = 0; $i < count($datos); $i++){
                            $id = $datos[$i]['id_controlAsis'];
                            $rutaEd = "/Jomar/users_control/controller/ControlAsisController.php?action=editar&id_controlAsis=$id";
                            $rutaEl = "/Jomar/users_control/controller/ControlAsisController.php?action=eliminar&id_controlAsis=$id";
                            echo "<tr>";
                            echo "<td>". ($i+1) ."</td>";
                            echo "<td style='width: 50px'> {$datos[$i]['fecha']} </td>";
                            echo "<td> {$datos[$i]['documento']} </td>";
                            echo "<td> {$datos[$i]['nombres']} </td>";
                            echo "<td> {$datos[$i]['apellidos']} </td>";
                            echo "<td> {$datos[$i]['sede']} </td>";
                            echo "<td> {$datos[$i]['siglas']} </td>";                                                          
                            echo "<td style='width: 200px'> {$datos[$i]['nota']} </td>";                            
                            echo "<td>
                            <a href='$rutaEd' class='badge badge-primary'>Editar </a>
                            <a href='$rutaEl' class='badge badge-warning'>Eliminar </a>
                            </td>";
                            echo "</tr>";
                        }

                    ?>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
    <?php
    }
    ?>
```

Gracias por su ayuda por anticipado

Comment: Como referencia SQL Server crea conectividad con Endpoints hacia servicios externos o implementa funciones CLR que usan servicios conectados para por ejemplo: Desde un trigger de actualizacion se comunica con dichos servicios conectados y notificar lo que se desea y el servicio (Ejemplo un servicio WCF Duplex o uno WebSocket) envia un mensaje al cliente final. Es lo más economico aunque complejo por su arquitectura pero de seguro veras ejemplos y concepto como este en internet

Comment: Muchas gracias, me toca estar investigando mucho más el concepto, gracias

Answer (score 4):

utilizando ajax podrías hacer que se realice una peticion cada cierto tiempo

ejemplo:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    function actualiza() {

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "actualiza.php",
            success: function(data) {
                $('#table tbody').html(data);
            }
        });
    }
    setInterval(actualiza, 3000);
});
</script>
```

en tu archivo actualiza.php

```
$html="";
 for($i = 0; $i < count($datos); $i++){
                            $id = $datos[$i]['id_controlAsis'];
                            $rutaEd = "/Jomar/users_control/controller/ControlAsisController.php?action=editar&id_controlAsis=$id";
                            $rutaEl = "/Jomar/users_control/controller/ControlAsisController.php?action=eliminar&id_controlAsis=$id";
                            $html.= "<tr>";
                            $html.= "<td>". ($i+1) ."</td>";
                            $html.= "<td style='width: 50px'> {$datos[$i]['fecha']} </td>";
                            $html.= "<td> {$datos[$i]['documento']} </td>";
                            $html.= "<td> {$datos[$i]['nombres']} </td>";
                            $html.= "<td> {$datos[$i]['apellidos']} </td>";
                            $html.= "<td> {$datos[$i]['sede']} </td>";
                            $html.= "<td> {$datos[$i]['siglas']} </td>";                                                          
                            $html.= "<td style='width: 200px'> {$datos[$i]['nota']} </td>";                            
                            $html.= "<td>
                            <a href='$rutaEd' class='badge badge-primary'>Editar </a>
                            <a href='$rutaEl' class='badge badge-warning'>Eliminar </a>
                            </td>";
                            $html.= "</tr>";
                        }
echo $html;
```

Comment: Gracias una buena idea, también se me ocurrio que cada vez que vaya a hacer una modificación en la base de datos directamente desde la pagina haga esa petición por ajax, lo intentaré, muchas gracias